# Div's using d-inline appear on two rows

Tags: bootstrap-4, inline, col

I'm trying to display two, or three, div's on one line but they always appear on two. Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/j6fau9h1/7/) and the code is below. The two blocks of code are the same except the second uses two div's since I thought that might make a difference, but it doesn't. How do I make all of this on one line in Bootstrap4 using row/col?

```
    <div class="row justify-content-center"> 
      <div class="col-3 d-inline-block">Title</div>     
      <form>
        <div class="col-2 d-inline-block">Search
           <input type="text" name="search">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>     
     
    <div class="row justify-content-center"> 
      <div class="col-3 d-inline-block">Title</div>     
      <form>
        <div class="col-2 d-inline-block">Search</div>
        <div class="col d-inline-block"><input type="text" name="search"></div>
      </form>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap rows (`.row`) and columns (`.col-*`) are built with flex box. The columns have to be the direct children of the rows in order for them to take effects. The fact that you have a `<form />` that wraps the search label and input breaks that.

If you want to make an inline form, there is a class `.form-inline` for that purpose: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/forms/#inline-forms

You can try the following layout for an inline form:

```html
<div class="container">    
    <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center"> 
        <div class="col-3">Title</div>     
        <form class="form-inline">
            <label for="search" class="mr-2">Search</label>
            <input id="search" type="text" name="search" class="form-control" />
        </form>
    </div>    
</div>
```

- `.align-items-center`: make items in the row vertically centered, optional
- `.form-inline`: make the form inline, required
- `.mr-2`: put right margin on the search label so that there is a gap between the form and itself, optional

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/Lt9fy6wb/11/

Comment: That worked perfectly. I appreciate you mentioning the vertical center since I was fighting that in another piece of code. Thank you.